# Why does Ajax keep asking Deadpool to say his name?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

Throughout the *Deadpool* movie after Ajax and Wade Wilson meet, Ajax keeps asking this,

> What's my name?

Throughout the movie it seems to be a theme. Does it have some special significance in or out of universe?

Comment: In the film Ajax uses it as a yardstick as to whether Deadpool has learned the proper respect

Comment: @Valorum, good point, I just could not find anything in or out as to why this was such a big theme.

Comment: It's a method of torture. I can't remember the name of the episode, but there was a Star Trek: TNG two parter in which Picard was tortured and his torturer wanted him to say there were 5 lights when there were only 4. Ajax is essentially doing the same thing. If Deadpool calls him Ajax, he wins-as long as Deadpool calls him Francis, he hasn't broken him.

Comment: @geewhiz: It's called ["Chain of Command"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_of_Command_%28Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation%29).

Comment: There are FOUR lights!

Comment: On reading the title of this question, I thought stackoverflow had created a new site for programming jokes.

Comment: Muhammad Ali v. Ernie Terrell: ["What's my name?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8ZZmkNo6-o)

Comment: "Throughout the Deadpool Movie, Ajax keeps asking" - don't you mean Francis, not Ajax?

Comment: The best part is that through half the movie, Deadpool is hunting down Ajax, asking everyone "Where's Francis?" before killing them, and *nobody knows who Francis is.*

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This article [explains this dynamic](http://nerdbastards.com/2016/02/14/7-awesome-moments-from-deadpool-the-movie/) in one of its points:

> **6. What’s My Name?**
>
> Ajax and Deadpool have quite a history in the comic series. Ajax loves
>   subjecting Deadpool to unfathomable torture while Deadpool loves
>   messing with the fact that Ajax’s real name is Francis. Their
>   relationship is perfectly translated on screen as Ajax asks Deadpool
>   what his name is throughout the film. **He wants to be called Ajax, but
>   the merc keeps calling him Francis, refusing to bow down to his
>   enemy’s demands.** This running theme culminates into a scene that’s
>   almost too awesome to be true.
>
> Just before his final battle with Ajax, Deadpool successfully takes
>   out a swarm of his henchmen armed with nothing but two katanas. After
>   asking what his name is constantly throughout the story, Ajax finds
>   Deadpool’s final answer literally laid out in front of him. The dead
>   henchmen are revealed to be precisely arranged on the ground by
>   Deadpool so that their corpses spell out “FRANCIS.” That’s a hell of a
>   way to own your arch enemy if you ask us.

Comment: Awesome answer, I had no idea that is what was going on!!! Up vote!!!

Comment: Your quote is a little off... the name is spelled "FRANCiS"* :P

Comment: TIL listicle. Straining to see _article_ as its origin tho. Other words keep bouncing to the front.

Answer (score 27):

- It's a show of dominance.
- Relatedly, it's a tell sign of breaking his nemesis.

Ajax confidently tells Deadpool that nobody's sense of humour survives Ajax's "clinic". And the most manifest sign of Deadpool's smart-assery is his making jokes about what Ajax's real name is.

So, when - instead of breaking under the torture - Deadpool triumphs on that topic by finding out Ajax's real name (name tag "Francis" left over from dry-cleaning), it makes Ajax uber-concentrated to reverse this. To him, having Deadpool admit that his name is Ajax is a signal that he won and broke Deadpool.

(the idea of using "tell me the lie is true" as a yardstick of breaking your opponent is, if course, nowhere near new, and not only borrowed from the Deadpool comics, but from much earlier archetypes, such as "How many fingers" in Orwell's *1984*).

Comment: There... Are... Four... Lights!

Comment: and also: "why did you resign?" repeatedly asked of number 6.